# Delphi - TSplitter align at runtime

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe

I have the following structure of panels

[image]

and from the code I need to align the bottom panel depending of situation on right,bottom or left. Align the splitter to right and bottom does not pose problems, but align the splitter to left I can't do

[image]

the code responsible for the alignment of the panels and splitters

```
procedure TForm1.alignThem;
begin
  case CommentPanelPosition of
        0: begin
            pROComponents.Align := alRight;
            sROSplitterComponents.Align := alRight;
            sROSplitterComponents.width := 3;

            pROComponents.Width := GridPanel.Width div 4;
          end;
       1:
        begin
          pROComponents.height := GridPanel.height div 3;
        end;
      2:
        begin
          pROComponents.Align := alLeft;
          TabellePanel.Align := alClient;
          sROSplitterComponents.Align := alLeft
        end;
  end;
end;
```

where

> CommentPanelPosition

is
0 when splitter is located on right
1 when splitter is located on bottom
2 when splitter is located on the left

How can I manage the problem when aligning the splitter to left?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After aligning the splitter, set `pROComponents.Left := 0;`,

```
begin
  pROComponents.Align := alLeft;
  TabellePanel.Align := alClient;
  sROSplitterComponents.Align := alLeft;
  pROComponents.Left := 0;
end;
```

You have two components that are aligned left (splitter and panel). The last one that is moved to the left is the splitter. It's left position is already 0 at that point, causing it to move to the far left and pushing the panel to the right.

So a different solution could be to first align the splitter left and then align the panel to the left.

But..

I believe that the Left-property at the moment of realigning is important, so if the panel was aligned right and the splitter as well, and you move them left (splitter first, then the panel), the panel will probably be right of the splitter again, because its `Left` property was greater than 0 at the time of realigning. 
Therefor, I feel safer by setting the appropriate property of the control(s) being split, so they are in the right position.

The splitter seems a smart component, but there is no way to directly associate it with two controls. When designing the form, or realigning it in code, the splitter has no idea which controls it belongs to and it will not attempt to position itself in a logical position inbetween your panels. It just follows the normal rules that apply to each control and only finds the right control when you actually start moving the splitter using your mouse.

So, setting the Left (or Right, Top, Bottom) property of the panel is actually just a work-around for this lacking functionality of the splitter.

Comment: Mmm I'm not sure, I have the right component. The component I meant was the component that should be left of the splitter. Maybe it is `pROComponents`? Looking at it again, I think `sROSplitterComponents` is the splitter itself. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Indeed. Thank you. +1 and accepted. For other users can you also please give a short explanation of why this solution is working?

Comment: I tried to explain it in my updated answer. Long story short: The splitter realigns as any other component, disregarding the panels it belongs to, so this is just a trick to work around that.

Comment: You don't have to. That explanation should have been there in the first place. ;)